# using fileinputstream to get part of encrypted file

Tags: java, file, file-io, inputstream, fileinputstream

I'm trying to decrypt a large file using
 https://github.com/martinwithaar/Encryptor4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encryptor4j/util/FileEncryptor.java
the following is part of decrypt method that i modified

```
                //the following does not work 
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
                fis.skip(83);
                is = encryptor.wrapInputStream(fis);
                os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                //the copy method is a default method from FileEncryptor.java
                copy(is, os);
```

the following works fine.(i have to decrypt entire file and then read/save part of file to another file then delete the old one and rename the new one to the old file name.

```
                is = encryptor.wrapInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
                os = new FileOutputStream(dest);

                copy(is, os);

                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(dest);
                fis.skip(67);
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(dest+".2");
                copy(fis,fos);
                new File(dest).delete();
                new File(dest+".2").renameTo(new File(dest));

                fis.close();
                fos.close();
```

my question is, why the code on top does not work? 
I followed http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/fileinputstream_skip.htm on how to skip some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Because the encrypted stream has state. The encryption of the 84th byte depends on the prior encryption history. Try this:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
is = encryptor.wrapInputStream(fis);
is.skip(83);
os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
// ...
```

Comment: You mean `skip()` returned zero? In that case you'll just have to read them, with the wrapped input stream.

Comment: the problem is that file is oversize ( bigger than MAX VALUE of integer), reading to byte array will result outofmemory error

Comment: You only need to skip 83 bytes, so you only need to read into an array of 83 bytes, but if you need to skip much more there's nothing that says you have to do it all in one read. But I checked the source code. The `Encryptor` returns a `javax.cipher.CipherInputStream`, which does implement `skip()`, so you shouldn't be having the problem of `skip()` returning zero, if indeed you are, which isn't clear. I can't actually see that this package adds any value over `CipherInputStream`.

Comment: indeed there is skip method in cipherInputStream. I will test again to see if it returns zero. but what i need to accomplish is that skipping 83 bytes and the remaining part is the one I need, also the remaining part is larger that integer max value